# ordering symptom list prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I have a dynamic list that contains a number of symptoms with a value of certainty.

ES: `[symptom (a, 0.93), symptom (b, 0.56), symptom (c, 0.59), symptom (d, 0.80)]`

I want to order the list in descending order according to the value of certainty.

ES: `[symptom (a, 0.93), symptom (d, 0.80), symptom (c, 0.59), symptom (b, 0.56)]`

Who can help me? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way is usually to map the list to another list and sort that with `keysort/2`. Here, I assume that you want the names sorted too, provided they have the same value.

```
element_to_pair(E, k(NegV,N) - E) :-
   E = symptom(N,V),
   NegV is -V.

nigrosort(Xs, Ys) :-
   maplist(element_to_pair,Xs, Ks),
   keysort(Ks, Ls),
   pairs_values(Ls, Ys).
```

Such tiny predicates as this `element_to_pair/2` often do not deserve a name of its own. It is too much to remember. With [`library(lambda)`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/lambda.pl) you can write more compactly:

```
:- use_module(library(lambda)).

nigrosort(Xs, Ys) :-
   maplist(\E^(k(NegV,N)-E)^( E = symptom(N,V), NegV is -V ),Xs, Ks),
   keysort(Ks, Ls),
   pairs_values(Ls,Ys).
```

Answer (score 1):

Which prolog environment are you using? SWI_Prolog has the predicate [predsort](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/swi/library/sort.pl), which can reorder a list using a custom predicate.

Answer (score 1):

```
..., predsort(compare_symptoms, L, Ordered), ...

compare_symptoms(<, symptom(_, PA), symptom(_, PB)) :-
  PA > PB.
compare_symptoms(>, _, _).
```

Note that we must avoid to return equality, or the system will remove symptoms with the same probability.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using ECLiPSe, you can use the `sort/4`predicate that allows to specify which argument of a term to use for sorting:

```
sort(2, >=, Symptoms, OrderedSymptoms)
```